# Auto log out when url change in browser tab

Tags: javascript, php, logout

I need to build a feature like most of the banks use. Where..

if user has log in to bank account in a browser tab & again he/she change the url of browser & move to some other site.. and again come to bank's page by clicking browser's BACK button.. then bank automatically log out user from there site.

I think may be by java script we can do this.. but, can not able to understand how to do this. I'm using PHP for my server side script. Is this, possible by PHP to do this..

Regards
Suresh

Comment: There is no accurate way to tell if a user leaves a page.

Comment: @AlexLunix About accurate.. can't say any thing. But, i've seen most of the bank account has such kind of feature. EX: City bank use such feature

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks!!!. I'll do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not a java/PHP question but depends on the exact behaviour you want to implement.

The only way to track the user "live" is through javascript. So if you want to know when the user leaves the page, you can bind yourself to an event listener and then do an ajax call or something like this that invalidates the session on the serverside. Keep in mind that users may be browsing your site with JS disabled, so you need a fallback on the serverside.

I would recommend you to implement session storage on the serverside with a storage mechanism (either the built-in PHP session store or some external storage like Couchbase or Redis, Memached,...) and set the logout time to a sane default (lower if it is something like a banking application).

If you have the basics in place, use JavaScript to enrich the user experience, for example by showing a "countdown" when the user will be logged out and sending session refresh ajax calls to the server to renew the session every time the user has an interaction with the website and such.

For more detailed information I'd need more requirements from your side!

Comment: Using AJAX in `onbeforeunload`/`onunload` will, I suspect, be unreliable. If the request takes too long or the server is for some reason unresponsive, I would expect the browser to abort/ignore the request because the browser's developers will be concerned about a websites ability to "trap" the user on a given page and destroy their user experience. I would say that the only reliable(ish) way to do this would be to have very short login session timeouts (maybe a minute or so) and use an ajax poll to keep the session alive, rather than the other way around.

Comment: @DaveRandom I've already implement the feature which u r talking about(short login session timeouts). But, i also want a feature like this.

Comment: @moidaschl 
When u fire AJAX call to server at the time of left to any other page.. there could b 2 condition occur.

1. Moving to any different site.
2. Moving to a another page of same site.

So, can u plz tell me how i can know.. whether user want to go any 'different site(1)' or user want to go a 'different page of same site(2)' before deleting the session in server side.